# Autotrack can't load in test site- but works in localhost

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm running into an issue where Autotrack and Google Analytics work fine when I'm testing it on localhost, but when I set up our domain in Google Analytics and attempt to test Autotrack/GA on our UAT test site, Autotrack can't find the javascript require statements to load Autotrack. I thought it might have something to do with our URL structure for the test site, but I can't modify that to test that theory.

The URL structure for the UAT test site is:

uat.ourtestsite.com/sb/

and here is a 
[Screenshot from ga_debugger in our test domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tat8U.jpg)

Here is Autotrack/GA [working in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyem.jpg)

Also important to note- the API call for Autotrack is coming though in localhost, but not at uat.ourtestsite.com/sb/

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in the console? When you run `ga('require', ...)`, if the plugin hasn't been [provided](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/writing-plugins#defining_a_plugin) in code, analytics.js [waits until it is](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/using-plugins#waiting_for_plugins_to_load). If it never gets provided, then no subsequent commands get run. So in your case it looks like you're not loading the autotrack `urlChangeTracker` plugin code on your test domain.

Comment: hello again @PhilipWalton. I figured it out. It actually had nothing to do with Autotrack. Our build was failing because the new package wasn't installed properly. It's fixed now and working great. But while I have your attention, I do have another question for you. Do you have any examples of setting up urlChangeTracker with React Router? I'm not exactly sure how that should all look and I haven't found any examples to learn from.  thanks! -Rachel

Comment: I don't have specific example of using autotrack with React Router (I've never used it), but it should work just fine if you configure it to use the HTML5 History API (as opposed to hash changes). If you're still having issue you should ask a new question to avoid too much discussion in the comments.

Comment: alright- thanks so much @PhilipWalton